# Geometry Problem -- Find the area of the circle

Tags: geometry

> Points $A, B, C, D$ are on a circle such that $AB = 10$ and $CD = 7$.
>   If $AB$ and $CD$ are extended past $B$ and $C$, respectively, they
>   meet at $P$ outside the circle. Given that $BP = 8$ and $∠AP D = 60º$,
>   ﬁnd the area of the circle.

---

Based on the information, I came up with the following sketch:

### [image]

Based, on the given info, and the theorem of geometry that states that the product of two secants and their external parts are equal to each other ($AP\cdot BP\; =\; \mbox{C}P\cdot DP$) I was able to find that $DP = 9$.

However, after this point I am stuck. I know I need to somehow find the radius, but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: I got that you can find $AC$ by law of cosines. However, how did you get that $∠AOC=60º$? If you are going by the inscribed angle theorem, $∠APD$ isn't an inscribed angle though. EDIT: The comment I responded to was removed...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Hint:*

$PD=AP/2 \to AD \perp PC$

Comment: How does that help you? From this You can find AD with pythagorean theorem, but how does that help you find the radius?

Comment: @user2612743 $AC$ is the diameter.

Comment: @user2612743 The triangle ADC is right-angled at D and AC is a diameter, hence you can apply the pythagorean theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Triangle $ADP$ is a right triangle, with the right angle at $D.$
Segment $AP = 18,$ with an intervening point $B$ which divides it so that $AB = 10$ and $BP = 8.$
Segment $PD = 9.$
Segment $DA = 9\sqrt{3}.$ Points $A,$ $B,$ and $D$ determine the required circle.

Now let's locate points on the Cartesian plane.
$$
A=\left(-\frac{9\sqrt 3}{2},0\right), \ \ 
D=\left(\frac{9\sqrt 3}{2},0\right), \ \ 
P=\left(\frac{9\sqrt 3}{2},9\right), \ \ 
B=\left(\frac{\sqrt 3}{2},5\right).
$$
The $y$-axis is the perpendicular-bisector of $AD.$
The intersection of the perpendicular-bisector of either $AB$ or $BD$ with the $y$-axis is the center of the required circle.

Answer (score 0):

Here $PD=AP/2$, hence $\triangle PDA$ is equilateral triangle. join $DB$ and use cosine formula to find $DB=\sqrt{91}$. Using circle property angle subtended by $DB$ at centre will be $120$ degree. Using Pythagoras theorem radius comes to be $\sqrt{91/3}$ hence area is $91\pi/3$.